# Sip <--> Lync Integration

Tags: sip, lync, ucma

I have a SIP app that I wish to connect to a Lync environment. So far I've set up a Static Route enabling the Lync Server to deliver SIP messages to my App. However, the messages I send to the Server are not being answered.

Is there any way to check if my app is correctly Authenticated to the Lync Server? how do I authenticate?

Also, googling around I read that in order to enable your App to talk to a Lync Server you have to use UCMA: is this true? I need to start from scratch? any guides? Microsoft's documentation is rather poor.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little background on integration. What you use depends on your application. There are multiple integration points to Lync 2010.

UCMA is typically used for automated end-points (IVRs, IM bots, routing applications, etc). If you're looking to build an application that answers a phone call or responds to an IM then UCMA is what you're looking for.

The Lync SDK is used for automating the Lync client application. This is somewhat akin to the classic Office Integration scenario where you want your application to say, start a mail-merge in Word for your end-user. If you're looking to to enable users to click phone numbers to initiate a call from within your application for example, you want to use the Lync SDK.

You stated that you have a SIP application here, but that is pretty general. Are we talking about a soft-phone? If so, DronNick is stop on - you need to enable TCP without TLS on your Lync Server. Because UCMA and Lync assume you have a standard Lync roll-out in place, it uses TLS for all communication. In very general level terms, UCMA **is** the SIP stack. If you've got an app with its own SIP stack then you shouldn't need to leverage UCMA at all.

Comment: Yes it is a SIP SoftPhone, but it is based on the RFC 3261, so it's not very compatible with Lync, but I am making the changes to adapt it.

I have enabled a TCP unencrypted SIP port just as DronNick and you have said. Now I should authenticate to the server, right? Any recommended libraries to do the NTML authentication with Lync?

Comment: Lync has the ability to work with analog phones. You could bypass the need for authentication by using this feature. Johann Deutinger wrote a great piece on setting this up at http://ucblog.deutinger.de/?p=6.

Comment: Yes, I knew that it wasn't necessary for PSTN connections, but I need to establish video sessions so that isn't an option, unfortunately... Thanks a lot for your help. I am currently trying to do the Authentication to Lync, will let you know how that works out!

Answer (score 1):

Lync requires a SIP connection via TLS. Do you have certificates installed on both sides(app and Lync)?

Also to investigate the problem better, you should make a Wireshark trace, to see if TLS works.

Comment: As far as I know, and from what I can read in the documentation, I can also use TCP to talk SIP to the server. TLS is an option, not a requirement.

Comment: Ok, but you have to enable TCP SIP without TLS first [link](http://www.confusedamused.com/notebook/enabling-unencrypted-tcp-connections-to-lync-on-port-5060/)